# Why do I get an error with reason "Actual or formal argument lists differs in length" when I calculate the minimum of an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, min

I'm getting the compile-time error

```
method min in class RandomArray cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.println(table.min());
                                ^
  required: int[]
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

but I don't understand why I get it?

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomArray {

    private int data[];
    private int value;

    public RandomArray(int x) {
        Random gen = new Random();
        data = new int[x];

        for (int index = 0; index < x; index++)
            data[index] = gen.nextInt(x);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output += data[i];
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static int min(int[] x) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < min) {
                min = x[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int data;
        System.out.println("please enter the number of integers you would like to create an array for");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        RandomArray table = new RandomArray(x);

        System.out.println(table.toString());
        System.out.println(table.min());
    }
}
```

Comment: The min method expects an argument and you didn't give any. But maybe that method should not have any arguments, not be static, and calculate the min of data?

Comment: can you put the complete code?

Comment: Yes, it should not be static. What do you mean not have an argument? My thinking is that I'm passing array 'x' through it, but it's not accepting array 'x'.

Comment: That is all of the code

Comment: No you're not passing array x in `table.min()` or it would be `table.min(x)`! But that's probably not what you should do.

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: Add a method `public int min() { return min(data); }`

Comment: *Giving you the benefit of the doubt I gave an answer...* However I strongly suggest you take the time to ***work through a proper [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)*** or a book on programming in Java. This will be much more effective than asking every (little) error you get when doing X in Java here on Stack Overflow (and it will also reduce the likelihood of getting down-votes).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others in the comments, you get this error

```
Error:(49, 33) java: method min in class RandomArray cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int[]
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

because you invoke your declared `public static int min(int[] x)` method without passing an argument when calling it with `table.min()`! Thus `actual and formal argument lists differ in length`.

*(Where `actual` refers to the method arguments of the invocation `table.min()`, a 0-length argument list, and `formal` to the declared method `int min(int[] x)` having 1-length argument list).*

Given your code, the argument which you want to pass into your `min` method is actually a memeber variable of your class `RandomArray` – the array `int data[]`. Because of that you should not pass any argument into your `min` method but instead make it operate directly on your `data []` array as in

```
public int min() {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] < min) {
            min = data[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Note that when you want a method in a class to operate on a *non-static memeber variable* such as your `private int data[];` array you need to make that method also non-`static`.

*(As a matter of style, instead of a C-style array declaration `int data[]` prefer the Java-style declaration `int[] data`).*

Putting it all together you get

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomArray {

    private int[] data;

    public RandomArray(int x) {
        Random gen = new Random();
        data = new int[x];

        for (int index = 0; index < x; index++) {
            data[index] = gen.nextInt(x);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }

    public int min() {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] < min) {
                min = data[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the number of integers you would like to create an array for");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        RandomArray table = new RandomArray(x);

        System.out.println(table.toString());
        System.out.println(table.min());
    }
}
```

giving you the output

```
please enter the number of integers you would like to create an array for
10
[9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 5, 4]
2
```